# Inverse Function Theorem and Injectivity

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function

I have the following problem (which involved the Inverse Function Theorem and Injectivity):

Let $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(u(x_1,x_2,x_3),v(x_1,x_2,x_3),w(x_1,x_2,x_3))$ be the mapping of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $u=x_1$, $v=x_1^2+x_2$, and $w=x_1+x_2^2+x_3^3$. The Jacobian of $f$ is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
2x_1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 2x_2 & 3x_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has determinant $3x_3^2$. As all the partials here are continuous, we know that $f$ is $C'$ on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Moreover, $f$ satisfies all of the conditions of the Inverse Function Theorem except for when $x_3=0$.

It is clear that $f$ is injective. Suppose $f(a,b,c)=f(x,y,z)$. The first coordinate gives $a=x$, using this in the second gives $b=y$, then using this in the third gives $c=z$ so that $f$ is everywhere injective.

The problem itself was simple enough. However, I have noticed many problems involving the Inverse Function Theorem and injectivity. But I'm not seeing the exact connection. Satisfying the Inverse Function Theorem gives only that there is *some* neighborhood on which $f$ is injective and hence has an inverse (which happens to be continuously differentiable). Why then all the questions connecting injectivity and the Inverse Function Theorem? Could one actually show a function is injective using the Inverse Function Theorem? Or is one always forced to check 'by hand' using something similar to what I did above?

Comment: Yes. The inverse function theorem, in its statement, *guarantees* the existence of a neighborhood of the point of interest, say ${\bf{x}}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, on which your function is injective. Most proofs I have seen use a modified Newton's method to test for injectivity on a sufficiently small neighborhood by means of approximating zeros. You can cook up an easy example of a non-injective func. only locally satisfying the hypotheses of the inverse function theorem. For instance, $f(x,y)=(e^{x}\cos(y),e^{x}\sin(y))$. (NB: $\cos^2(y)+\sin^2(y)=1$, $\arctan(\tan(y))=y$, $y\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$)

Comment: @Nobody Then would the answer not be that the Inverse Function Theorem never says anything about injectivity as it only looks at local injectivity? Or if the the function satisfies the Inverse Function Theorem everywhere, there is an injective neighborhood for all $x$ in the domain so that the function is everywhere injective. But for those not satisfying the IFT everywhere, we always need to make an argument as I did above?

Comment: The inverse function theorem tells you that there exists a nbhd of $f$ at every point for which its Jacobian is nonzero. The restriction of $f$ to that neighborhood induces an injection onto the image of said nbhd under $f$. If the neighborhood were $N$, then the function $\left.f\right|_{\small{N}}$ is an injection onto its image.

Comment: Ex: Consider $f(x,y)=(x^2,y)$, $J_{f}(x,y)=
\begin{vmatrix}
2x & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=2x$. Consider the point $p=(\varepsilon,1)$, $\varepsilon>0$. One nbhd that works is simply the set of all points a distance less than or equal to $\varepsilon$ away from $p$. If you chose this radius greater than $\varepsilon$, say $\varepsilon+\delta$, then there would be points $(-\delta/2,1)$ and $(\delta/2,1)$ in your nbhd for which $f(-\delta/2,1)=f(\delta/2,1)$.